# Passing a Base64 encoded String into sha512 function gives different result than when hard coded

Tags: java, android, hash, base64, sha

I'm coding in Android Studio and I'm trying to create base64 encoded and sha512 hashed String.

The functions are:

```
private String getBase64(String data){

    try{

        byte[] enc = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
        return Base64.encodeToString(enc, Base64.DEFAULT);

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}

private String getSHA(String data){

    try {

        MessageDigest mda = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        byte[] digesta = mda.digest(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        return convertByteToHex(digesta);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}


public String convertByteToHex(byte data[]) {
    StringBuilder hexData = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte aData : data)
        hexData.append(String.format("%02x", aData));
    return hexData.toString();
}
```

Then calling them:

```
    // line below prints VGVzdDox as it should
    Log.d("GO", "Working Base64: " + getBase64("Test:1"));

        // line below prints: 3553AF9EDC389314B0F7354B51FEA7EB089C039EA77A0FD7BD61798A8DD14B1292B353B9E00789B2698B072AF5B05417DDDAA1870ADF9E1DE9C1F96D9465DF56
    // as it should
    Log.d("GO", "Working SHA: " + getSHA("VGVzdDox"));


    String b = getBase64("Test:1");

    // line below prints VGVzdDox again, as it should
    Log.d("Base64", b);

    String s = getSHA(b);

    // Now this line prints a7d1bdc5d6497d787b35ce52774365150a2e21084958ffc14570367f3764b938fc1191d06006f1908084518c9697cbff3f2830a1ac003ef8ace36a0667dce92d
    // Not sure why?
    Log.d("SHA", s);
```

So that last output is wrong. However the `getBase64` is right and the `getSHA` also when hard coding the base64 encoded String. And I have no idea why.
This is just the main activity, no other code is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, had to change:

```
return Base64.encodeToString(enc, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

to

```
return Base64.encodeToString(enc, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems like your String

```
b
```

have a new line at the end, i tested it with an online sha 512 generator with the String:

"VGVzdDox" and

"VGVzdDox

"

output of the first one is:

```
3553AF9EDC389314B0F7354B51FEA7EB089C039EA77A0FD7BD61798A8DD14B1292B353B9E00789B2698B072AF5B05417DDDAA1870ADF9E1DE9C1F96D9465DF56
```

the out put for the second is:

```
A7D1BDC5D6497D787B35CE52774365150A2E21084958FFC14570367F3764B938FC1191D06006F1908084518C9697CBFF3F2830A1AC003EF8ACE36A0667DCE92D
```

so get rid of the line seperator maybe with the method Stirng.trim(), but i didn't tested it

Comment: I think so as well. I got it to output on one line using the flag Base64.NO_WRAP in the encode function.